# I got a job offer in Germany. Can I bring my family with me at the same time?

Tags: working-visas, germany, family, egyptian-citizens

I got a job offer in Germany, and I have an apartment for me and my family (wife and son) - offered by the company. The question is:

1. Can I apply for a **national visa** (long-stay) for me and my family to bring them with me from the first time?
2. If so, what documents needed for that purpose, and
3. How long it takes?

We (me, wife, and son) are Egyptians, and my son is 2 years old

Comment: If you can't, don't take the job.

Comment: I have the exact same question, were you able to go with your family the first time?

Comment: @Asimov see the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it was possible to bring them from the very beginning, but I should have made a ***family appointment*** (not single one), and we are done